# Using a trait to change a variable in another class results in slower performance

Tags: php, performance, oop

I had some free time and decided to benchmark a couple of options for a custom logging system I will be implementing in my application. The point is to simply log events during execution from different classes and functions into an array that can later be examined.

While trying these out I saw something that puzzled me: **Using a trait to modify a variable in another class takes longer than modifying a variable in "self". It also takes longer than modifying the variable directly.**

I'm not exactly interested in miniscule performance gains, and have not yet decided on the final implementation either. I'm just curious about why this happens.

Here's the code to test it. I also did some other tests, but they were slower for obvious reasons.

```
class ExternalStore {
    public static $log = [];
}

trait LoggerTrait {
    public static function addLog($time, $event) {
        return [$time, $event];
    }
}

echo "<h1>Changing external variable directly</h1>";
class ExternalAppend {
    public function doStuff() {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
            ExternalStore::$log += [microtime(), "Stuff done"];
        }
    }
}

$ExternalAppend = new ExternalAppend;
$start = microtime(true);
$ExternalAppend->doStuff();
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
echo "Execution time: $time<hr>"; // ~0.18...

echo "<h1>Using a trait to change internal variable</h1>";
class TraitUser {
    use LoggerTrait;

    public static $log = [];

    public function doStuff() {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
            self::$log += self::addLog(microtime(), "Stuff done");
        }
    }
}

$TraitUser = new TraitUser();
$start = microtime(true);
$ExternalAppend->doStuff();
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
echo "Execution time: $time<hr>"; // ~0.18...

echo "<h1>Using a trait to change external variable</h1>";
class TraitUserExternal {
    use LoggerTrait;

    public function doStuff() {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
            ExternalStore::$log += self::addLog(microtime(), "Stuff done");
        }
    }
}

$TraitUserExternal = new TraitUserExternal();
$start = microtime(true);
$TraitUserExternal->doStuff();
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
echo "Execution time: $time<hr>"; // ~0.30...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally had some time to look into this and the solution was simple. **The problem was calling `$ExternalAppend->doStuff()` instead of `$TraitUser->doStuff()` on `line 41`.** After fixing this the execution times of `TraitUser` and `TraitUserExternal` are similar. There is also a mistake of using `$var += [$val1, $val2]` instead of `$var[] = [$val1, $val2]`, but that doesn't seem to affect the differences. Only the total execution time.

Slower performance in `TraitUser` and`TraitUserExternal` compared to `ExternalAppend` comes from the combined overhead of calling a function and using a return value.

The following code confirms the findings. Modifying a variable directly without calling any functions is the fastest way. Calling a function and modifying the variable there is the second fastest. Third (marginally slower than the second) way is modifying a variable with a value returned from a function.

The fourth function `doStuff4()` also shows a better way of using a trait to modify a variable in another class.

```
<?php
trait Logger {
    protected static function modifyInternalValue($time, $event) {
        self::$internalLog[] = [$time, $event];
    }
    protected static function returnValue($time, $event) {
        return [$time, $event];
    }
    protected static function modifyExternalValue($time, $event) {
        ExternalLogger::$externalLog[] = [$time, $event];
    }
}

class ExternalLogger {
    public static $externalLog = [];

    public static function modifyValue($time, $event) {
        self::$externalLog[] = [$time, $event];
    }

}

class LoggerUser {
    use Logger;

    public static $internalLog = [];
    protected static $iterations = 10000;

    public function doStuff1() {
        echo "<h1>1 - Directly modifying an internal variable</h1>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < self::$iterations; $i++) {
            self::$internalLog[] = [microtime(), "Stuff done"];
        }
    }
    public function doStuff2() {
        echo "<h1>2 - Trait returns a value to internal variable</h1>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < self::$iterations; $i++) {
            self::$internalLog[] = self::returnValue(microtime(), "Stuff done");
        }
    }
    public function doStuff3() {
        echo "<h1>3 - Trait modifies a variable inside a function</h1>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < self::$iterations; $i++) {
            self::modifyInternalValue(microtime(), "Stuff done");
        }
    }
    public function doStuff4() {
        echo "<h1>4 - Trait modifies a variable of an external class</h1>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < self::$iterations; $i++) {
            self::modifyExternalValue(microtime(), "Stuff done");
        }
    }
    public function doStuff5() {
        echo "<h1>5 - External class modifies a variable in itself</h1>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < self::$iterations; $i++) {
            ExternalLogger::modifyValue(microtime(), "Stuff done");
        }
    }
}

function profileFunction($function) {
    $LoggerUser = new LoggerUser();
    $start = microtime(true);
    $LoggerUser->$function();
    $time = microtime(true) - $start;
    echo "Execution time: $time<hr>";
}

profileFunction("doStuff1"); // Fast    | Direct modification
profileFunction("doStuff2"); // Slowest | Function returns a value
profileFunction("doStuff3"); // Slower  | Function modifies a value
profileFunction("doStuff4"); // Slower  | Function modifies external class
profileFunction("doStuff5"); // Slower  | External class modifies itself
```